# Scan directory for files (while ignoring directories)

Tags: swift, file, directory

Is there not a way to use this function to skip directories?
What I'm trying to do is make an array of urls to all of the files in a folder, while skipping directories.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

```
let urls = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: u, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants, .skipsSubdirectoryDescendants])
```

Comment: Ask `FileManager` if any of files is a directory?

Comment: isDirectory: &ObjCBool... right.
Thanks!